# I'm trying to detect if the caption button is clicked on google meet

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to see if there's a way to detect if the caption button was clicked on google meet using a chrome extension. Here's what I currently have

```
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe fzRBVc tmJved xHd4Cb rmHNDe Qr8aE');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
```

I'm currently getting an error that states:

content.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

}

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, so you would want to do `button[0].addEventListener`. I'm also not certain that you can put space separated classNames in that method - if I was you I'd focus on just `.getElementsByClassName('VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe')`. Finally, you need to verify that those classNames are consistent in ever instance of google meet - they might change from reload to reload or user to user.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let button = document.getElementsByClassName('VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe fzRBVc tmJved xHd4Cb rmHNDe Qr8aE')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('clicked');
})
```

getElementsByClassName returns an array. You can try updating the code as below. If there is more than one element of the same class, you can try looping and listening to all of them. But this is not recommended.

Comment: I tried it using it with the one specific element, and still got this same error  content.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: If you are getting the "undefined" error, it is because there is no element with the classes you specified in the dom. Using more than one class can cause this error.

Comment: you can try something like this


https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/awuzoqeciy.js

Comment: Hi I just tried this and the length of button is showing up as 0 causing it to not even get into the first if statement

Comment: Can you copy and post the div element that covers the subtitle button?

Comment: Do you want the div class or the button class?

Comment: i want div html codes

Comment: <div class="TlJx6e"> it's nested inside of this div class which also has this nested in it <div jsaction="JIbuQc:QODBq;rcuQ6b:Q313Se" class="Q8K3Le" jscontroller="U1Cub">

Comment: please upload and post all html code to hastebin. https://hastebin.com/

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/xeduxebase.xml

Comment: In order to listen to the click event of the button according to the class names, it is necessary to access that button first. If the class name of the button you want to listen to is used in more than one button, it will be more difficult for you to access the button we want to click. I suggest you draw a unique path to this button. You could try to access the button by navigating the divs that contain it. 

I just wrote an experimental code, I'm not sure it will work for you. You can test it.
https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/kezodosahi.yaml

Comment: Hi bahri, I did attempt this and found no success with it sadly. Do you have any other suggestions?